# What does "rub a butt on him" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

From the movie *Red Dawn*:

In a scene, a group of young fighters interrogate an enemy soldier. One of them says, "Rub a butt on him." And another one goes on to seemingly pinch the enemy soldier really hard. I found a clip of that scene [here](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/4239045d-fbbd-4d29-bd2c-fad1f3b41a93).

What does "rub a butt on him" mean here? To pinch someone's face so hard that it looks like a butt?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm afraid that "butt" here means a cigarette: he is telling her to torture the prisoner with a lit cigarette, which she then does.